# Why dialog not disappearing when using showDialog?

Tags: flutter, showdialog

I am using tabBar.If I click on the first tab and on the second tab many times and very fast then showDialog(loading) not disappearing. It stays on the screen eternally. I tried to fix that for a long time but I can't find a solution

This is the code of the first tab(widget not converted in BlocConsumer):

```
class FirstWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const FirstWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<FirstWidget> createState() => _FirstWidgetState();
}

class _FirstWidgetState extends State<FirstWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TabBar(
  onTap: (index) async {
    if (index == 0) {

    final connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
    if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi ||
      connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.ethernet) {
        showWaiting(context); // Here is the loader, if I remove it then loader won't show up when I get data. So I just put it here and because of him my app is freezing
        BlocProvider.of<StatisticsCubit>(context).getData();
      }
    }
    },
    tabs: [
      Tab(
        icon: SizedBox(
        width: 60.w,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text(
                "First",
                style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 14.sp,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                height: 1,
                color: Colors.white
                ),
              ),
              ],
            ),
        ),
      ),
      Tab(
        icon: SizedBox(
        width: 60.w,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text(
                "Second",
                style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 14.sp,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                height: 1,
                color: Colors.white
                ),
              ),
              ],
            ),
        ),
      )
    ],
  );
  }
}
```

This is the widget when I press seconds tab:

```
class SecondWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const SecondWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<SecondWidget> createState() => _SecondWidgetState();
}

class _SecondWidgetState extends State<SecondWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<StCubit, StState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state is Waiting) {
          showWaiting(context, false);
        }
        if (state is Success) {
          Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
        }
      },
      builder: (context, state) {
        return Container();//content
      },
    );
  }
}
```

This is a loader:

```
Future<void> showWaiting(BuildContext context) {
  return showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) => Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
      child: const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
          strokeWidth: 1,
          color: Colors.black,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    )
  );
}
```

The loader not disappearing when I click many times on the first and the second tab

Answer (score 1):

It is because there is high possibility that the dialogs are getting stacked up, So you have to first pop the existing dialog before showing the new one.

Try the updated code.

```
Future<void> showWaiting(BuildContext context) async {
  // Dismiss any previously shown dialog
  Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop(); // This should possibly fix the issue

  // Show the new dialog
  await showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) => Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
      child: const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
          strokeWidth: 1,
          color: Colors.black,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but id didn't help me. If I click on the tab with loader then it main widget and I can see only orange screen of empty widgets. Maybe I can replace showDialog on something better oracle only one instance of showDialog?